# Convert GridView into One Row

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

I have a Grid View which I turned from 2 columns, to one column. I want to make this grid view into one scrolling row, similar to how Google Photos does. This is so I can have a scrolling row of albums at the top, and then have individual photos at the top. In the pictures shown below are what I have (Screenshot with Red toolbar) vs Google Photos (What I want, as far as the rows go)

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: post your expected output screenshot

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I already have. Check the screenshot below my app. My app is the one with the red tool bar. My expected result is the one below that (the three folders, with camera, screenshots, and Allo as the names). This was posted in the original post

Comment: use recyclerview instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Gridview you can use Recyclerview it will give you result. Try like this

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),3);
```

https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/grid-recyclerview-with-images-and-text.html

Comment: Okay, thank you. After some tinkering, I got it to work with RecyclerView. However, it seems to have a problem with scrolling. This might just be a bug with the emulator, however, as this does not happen on my phone.